# sudo / su to user in a specific group

Tags: linux, sudo, su

I am looking to setup a generic user that has the ability to `su/sudo` to any user in a specific group. Either that or to any user that has a specific naming scheme.

Is this possible on linux?

I should also mention I don't want the user to be able to go full root

Comment: I don't think I can understand fully what you are trying to do. Can you explain a little bit more what are you trying to do and what do you want to achieve or why are you doing this?

Comment: Trying to make a script that needs to access access specific environment variables that multiple users have. So the specific commands need to run as those users. I do not however want the script to run as root so I wanted to create a new user specifically to do the jumping around. Hope that helps

Comment: You want to read a users environment variables. Is this correct? Where from? There `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: read and execute commands as them. Not quite sure where they are stored. Not in those two locations though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using `sudo`. Use `%<group-name>` for the `RunAs` list. For example, with the following rule:

```
sysad ALL = (%wheel) ALL
```

And the following group configuration:

```
$ getent group wheel
wheel:x:10:root,muru
```

We get the following amusing effect:

```
$ sudo -u sysad bash -c 'echo $USER'
Sorry, user sysad is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/bash' as sysad on muru-arch.
$ sudo -u root bash -c 'echo $USER'
root
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible via editing your sudors file .

```
lnydex99uhc:~ user$ ls /etc/sudoers 
/etc/sudoers
```

Fistly , run the below command to print out the current sudo configuration.

```
sudo -ll | column -t
```

Example Entries

To allow a user to gain full root privileges when he/she precedes a command
with sudo, add the following line:

```
USER_NAME   ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

To allow a user to run all commands as any user but only the machine with hostname HOST_NAME:

```
USER_NAME   HOST_NAME=(ALL) ALL
```

To allow members of group wheel sudo access:

```
%wheel      ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

To disable asking for a password for user USER_NAME:

```
Defaults:USER_NAME      !authenticate
```

Enable explicitly defined commands only for user USER_NAME on host HOST_NAME:

and at last, be very careful with this unless you have no option but to do it this way . Newly added user will be privileged enough to take over the machine.

Want to read more, here you go [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo) , [link2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos)

One more last thing to read before you start editing your file.

**

```
This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
# Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
# that prevent sudo from running.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
```

**